# How can make a drop down menu like this in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

[Drop down menu](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/screenshot20091217at142.png/)
I was wondering how i could make a drop down menu? And how could you make it go upwards instead of downwards? I have an idea how to get it started but the buttons would have no functionality.  Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), perhaps. This supports popping up or down based on space, but it is only available on Honeycomb or higher.